# Is there a way to use a testing database in catalyst

Tags: perl, catalyst

When using catalyst is there a way to specify a dev, test and production database like you would in Rails?  I have looked through the documentation but I haven't found an answer.

Comment: Have you read [this](http://www.catalystframework.org/calendar/2005/19)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With reference from cpan [Catalyst Testing Tutorial](http://search.cpan.org/~zarquon/Catalyst-Manual-5.8005/lib/Catalyst/Manual/Tutorial/08_Testing.pod#SUPPORTING_BOTH_PRODUCTION_AND_TEST_DATABASES)

> You may wish to maintain both a "production database" for your live application and a
>   "testing database" for your test cases.
>
> **DATABASE CONFIG SWITCHING IN YOUR MODEL CLASS**
>
> One solution is to allow the database specification to be overridden with an environment variable. For example, open lib/MyApp/Model/MyAppDB.pm in your editor and change the
>   `__PACKAGE__->config(...` declaration to resemble:
>
> ```
> my $dsn = $ENV{MYAPP_DSN} ||= 'dbi:SQLite:myapp.db';
> __PACKAGE__->config(
>     schema_class => 'MyAppDB',
>     connect_info => [
>         $dsn,
>         '',
>         '',
>         { AutoCommit => 1 },
>
>     ],
> );
> ```
>
> Then, when you run your test case, you can use commands such as:
>
> $ cp myapp.db myappTEST.db
>    $ CATALYST_DEBUG=0
>   MYAPP_DSN="dbi:SQLite:myappTEST.db" prove --lib lib -v t/live_app01.t
>
> This will modify the DSN only while the test case is running. If you
>   launch your normal application without the MYAPP_DSN environment
>   variable defined, it will default to the same dbi:SQLite:myapp.db as
>   before.
>
> **DATABASE CONFIG SWITCHING USING MULTIPLE CONFIG FILES**
>
> By utilizing [Catalyst::Plugin::ConfigLoader](http://search.cpan.org/~bricas/Catalyst-Plugin-ConfigLoader-0.30/lib/Catalyst/Plugin/ConfigLoader.pm)s functionality for loading
>   multiple config files based on environment variables you can override
>   your default (production) database connection settings.
>
> Setting $ENV{ MYAPP_CONFIG_LOCAL_SUFFIX } to 'testing' in your test
>   script results in loading of an additional config file named
>   myapp_testing.conf after myapp.conf which will override any parameters
>   in myapp.conf.
>
> You should set the environment variable in the BEGIN block of your
>   test script to make sure it's set before your Catalyst application is
>   started.
>
> The following is an example for a config and test script for a
>   DBIx::Class model named MyDB and a controller named Foo:
>
> myapp_testing.conf:
>
> ```
> <Model::MyDB>
>     <connect_info>
>         dsn dbi:SQLite:myapp.db
>     </connect_info>
> </Model::MyDB>
> ```

Also check [this](http://wiki.dandascalescu.com/howtos/catalyst/using_dbicx%3a%3atestdatabase_with_catalyst) when using seperate databases